# Parameter passing error

Tags: c++

I have made a function like this:

```
void function(Objectx &x);
```

And I call the function like this:

```
Objectx o;
function(o);
```

in the same class.

When I compile it I get this:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘function(Objectx)’
note: candidate is: void function (Objectx&)
```

Sorry if is a lame question, but I didn't find a solution anywhere. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you only declared the function not defined it

Comment: I think we need more information.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you've shown the real code causing the error.  (For one thing, the alleged code has `Obectx` and the error says `Objectx`)

That error would occur if you passed a temporary value (rvalue), because an non-`const` reference cannot bind to an rvalue.

If the function doesn't change its parameter, change the signature to:

```
void function(const Objectx &x);
```

If the function does change its parameter, you will need to store the temporary value to a variable, and pass the variable.  That way any changes made by the function end up in a variable you can access after the call.

Comment: Maybe Objectx vs. Obectx is the issue :)

Comment: Here is the real code:

    void PluginKateXMLEditView::intialDistributionOfTags(QVector<KTextEditor::Range> &src);
     intialDistributionOfTags(rangesList(kd->documentRange()));

rangesList returns QVector<KTextEditor::Range>

Comment: That's _temporary value_ issue

Comment: @yonutix: It is just as my crystal ball foresaw.  If you save the return value to a variable, and pass the variable, things will work.